If the current through an inductor can't change suddenly, how it can induce voltage in the ignition coil of a car?
In an igniton coil, there is a  voltage induced in the secondary when the switch is changed position.  According to Lenz's law, the primary coil in the ignition coil will try to continue flowing the current in the same way so there is no change in the current's flow. How can it induce a voltage across the secondary winding?


the collapsing magnetic field induces voltage in the secondary winding

the primary coil in the ignition coil will try to continue flowing the current in the same way so there is no change in the current's flow ... the conclusion is not correct

Heh. Regarding the use of "can't", the reflection at the top here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/721600/311631 may prove of interest.

There was always a capacitor, typically 220 nF, parallel to the right switch to define the shape of the ignition pulse and to protect the switch contacts.

serkan - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the source webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

Alternately, you may find it helpful to think of the energy stored in the inductance, rather than the behavior of the magnetic field, when trying to understand inductor behavior.
The energy stored in the inductance due to its current (1/2 LI²) must be dissipated before the current can stop, so the inductor will do whatever is required, to keep that current flowing until there's no energy left.
In the case of a coupled inductor, such as a flyback transformer (ignition coil), the energy is stored from the initial primary current flow.
When that primary current is then suddenly interrupted by points or a transistor, the inductive energy causes the primary voltage to rapidly rise, along with the secondary voltage due to transformer coupling, until it finds a conductive path (with an ignition coil, that's through the secondary winding sparkplug gap).
(In case you are wondering where the energy goes if the secondary is open, there would be a very high-voltage oscillation formed in the coil by the inductance resonating with the stray coil and external circuit capacitance.  If this high voltage doesn't break down the insulation and generate an arc, then the oscillation continues until the energy is dissipated in the coil's internal series resistance.)


According to Lenz's law, the primary coil in the ignition coil will try to continue flowing the current in the same way ...

Correct.

... so there is no change in the current's flow.

Incorrect.
If your statement were true you could never switch off the current through an inductor.
From the inductor equation, \$ V = L\frac {di}{dt} \$ we can see that a sudden change in current will induce a high voltage across the coil primary which will appear at the opening points. So you can always change the current but there will be an effect somewhere else in the circuit.

The key point is that an ignition coil is a transformer, not just an inductor.
While these are composed of similar elements, a transformer has coupling between the 2 windings. Lenz's law doesn't allow the flux to change 'instantly' but that doesn't prevent which winding which is generating the flux to change from one to the other 'quickly'.
Thus in an ignition coil, you build up current in one winding (the primary), and there is zero current in the (more turns) secondary. When you interrupt the current in the primary, multiple things happen:
The flux tries to stay constant -- so I_primaryN_primary + I_secondaryN_Secondary stays constant. If you make the primary current = 0, then the secondary current will replace it.
Consequently, the secondary V will rise (until the current actually flows), and this will induce a (transformer) voltage in the primary with a factor of N_primary/N_secondary of the secondary voltage.

As primary current increases the magnetic particles becomes polarised in one direction more and more and core field strenght continue to increase.
Once the primary current starts to fall or even becomes zero the magnetic domains cannot be held polarised anymore in this direction, they changes orientation (magnetic field change) , hence they induce an opposite voltage in both windings.
If the windings are loaded with some resistance the current is presented also.


If the current through an inductor can't change suddenly, how it can induce (high) voltage in the ignition coil of a car?

The actual rate of change of current depends on the L/R = Tau for 63% decay.  So when an inductor has low resistance the change is slow on the order of L/R = xx milliseconds or a straight wire on the order of microseconds or less.
But when dry contacts open to air the resistance Tau reduces dt on the order of xxx nanoseconds which negates the assumption that "the current cannot change quickly" so that V= LdI/dt can achieve several hundred volts on the primary side.
It is better to think it "resists changing quickly". (L/R ratio)
As I recall, the contacts move far enough so that the low voltage side doesn't arc on open but the secondary has a turns ratio to generate 40 kV at 1 atmosphere and lower voltage under 8 atm pressure for a compression ratio of 8:1.
